# Error when appending string from word or variable

Tags: forth, gforth

I'm trying to append two strings in gforth, but I get some scary looking error messages.

While `s" foo" s" bar" append type cr` works fine, as soon as I start storing strings in variables or creating them from words, I get errors.  For instance:

```
: make-string ( -- s )
    s" foo" ;

: append-print ( s s -- )
    append type cr ;

make-string s" bar" append-print
```

Running it produces the following error:

```
$ gforth prob1.fs -e bye
gforth(41572,0x7fff79cc2310) malloc: *** error for object 0x103a551a0: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Abort trap: 6.
```

I'm well versed in C, so it seems pretty clear that I'm using Forth **incorrectly**!
I suppose I need to learn something very basic about memory management in Forth.

Can anyone please explain what goes wrong here, and what I *should* do?

I also run into problems when I try to append a string that is stored in a variable:

```
variable foo
s" foo" foo !

foo s" bar " append type cr
```

This ends in a loop that I have to break:

```
$ gforth prob2.fs
foo��^C
in file included from *OS command line*:-1
prob2.fs:4: User interrupt
foo s" bar " append >>>type<<< cr
Backtrace:
$10C7C2E90 write-file
```

For reference, I'm using gforth 0.7.2 on Mac OS X.  I would be very grateful for some good explanations on what's going on.

**Update**

I can see the definition of `append`:

```
see append
: append
  >l >l >l >l @local0 @local1 @local3 + dup >l resize throw >l @local4 @local0 @local3 + @local5
  move @local0 @local1 lp+!# 48 ; ok
```

So, it would seem I need to manage memory myself in Forth?  If so, how?

**Solution**

Andreas Bombe provides the clue below.  The final program that works would be

```
: make-string ( -- s )
  s" foo" ;

: append-print
  s+ type cr ;

make-string s" bar" append-print
```

Output is

```
$ gforth b.fs -e bye
foobar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` uses `resize` on the first string make space to append the second string. This requires that the string be allocated on the heap.

When you compile a string with `s"` into a word, it gets allocated in the dictionary. If you try `resize` (directly or indirectly through `append`) on that pointer you will get the error you see.

Normally `s"` has undefined interpretation semantics. Gforth defines its interpretation semantics for convenience as allocating the string on the heap. That's why it works (in gforth) as long as you don't compile it.

*Edit:*

I've found the definition of `append`, it's part of `libcc.fs` (a foreign function interface builder as it seems) and not a standard word. This is the definition in the source, more readable than the `see` decompile:

```
: append { addr1 u1 addr2 u2 -- addr u }
    addr1 u1 u2 + dup { u } resize throw { addr }
    addr2 addr u1 + u2 move
    addr u ;
```

Immediately before that is a definition of `s+`:

```
: s+ { addr1 u1 addr2 u2 -- addr u }
    u1 u2 + allocate throw { addr }
    addr1 addr u1 move
    addr2 addr u1 + u2 move
    addr u1 u2 +
;
```

As you can see this one allocates new memory space instead of resizing the first string and concatenates both strings into it. You could use this one instead. It is not a standard word however and just happens to be in your environment as an internal implementation detail of `libcc.fs` in gforth so you can't rely on it being available elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. But do you have a suggestion on how I could write the example above? Do I have to use `CREATE` to create a string first? (I would be happy if you did, so I can accept this answer --- sorry for asking, and I'll probably accept it anyway, but t would be nice for the site)

Answer (score 1):

The usage of strings in Forth doesn't warrant dynamic allocation mostly and at least not in your example. You can get by nicely with buffers that you allocate yourself using ALLOT
and some very simple words to manipulate them.

[ALLOT uses the data space (ANSI term) in an incremental fashion for adding words and buffers. It is not dynamic, you can't release an item without removing at the same time all items ALLOT-ted later. It is also simple. Do not confuse with ALLOCATE which is dynamic and is in a separate extension  wordset]

You make a fundamental mistake in leaving out the specification of your append-buffer.
It doesn't work, and we don't know how it is supposed to work!

In ciforth's an example could be:

```
 : astring S" foo" ;    

  CREATE buffer 100 ALLOT \ space for 100  chars 

  \ Put the first string in `buffer and append the second string.

  \ Also print the second string

 : append-print ( s s -- )

 type cr 2swap   

 buffer $!  

 buffer $+! ;   

 astring s" bar" append-print 

  bar OK \ answer

  buffer $@ TYPE 

  foobar OK \ answer
```

Other Forths have other non-standard words to manipulate simple strings. An excursion through malloc land is really not necessary. In the gforth documentation  you can look up 'place' and find an equivalent family of words.

Also nowadays (Forth 2012) you can have strings like so "foo".

Comment: What's the difference between dynamic allocation and a buffer? Is the buffer allocated on the stack?

Comment: Oops, I should not have assumed such knowledge. Edited the answer.